# MonetDBLite dir does get smaller after table drop

Tags: r, monetdblite

Every time I drop a table and import new data in a newly create table, the footprint of MonetDBLite keeps getting larger. Is there anything like a sweep I need to do to reclaim the space every time a table is dropped? Here is the snippet I use to drop and import data into tables.

```
conn <- dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), dbdir)
if (dbExistsTable(conn, 'my_events'))
   dbRemoveTable(conn, 'my_events')
monetdb.read.csv (conn, dbdir, 'my_events.csv', 'my_events')
```

Comment: what happens if you restart the db? e.g `dbDisconnect(conn, shutdown=T)` and then `dbConnect()` again?

Comment: I must not have those statements in my code before. It seem to be working properly now. Thanks for your reply.